# Find folder without certain file in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have subfolders, and subsubfolders. In the subsubfolders, I want to find all subfolders without a file named PKA.dump. Can this be done in powershell?

The subfolders go from Angle1, Angle2, etc up to Angle24

The subsubfolders go from 1eV, 2eV, to 150eV.

I can find when they are less than a certain size:

```
Get-Childitem -path .  -filter "PKA.dump" -recurse | where {$_.Length -le 500}
```

But what if they dont exist?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730955.aspx

Comment: @DeanSpicer If I say, do a:

Test-Path . -include PKA.dump, how can I get it to go through all subsubfolders and let me know which one is False?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, something like this should work:

```
gci -Filter *eV -Directory -Recurse | 
    ? { -not (Test-Path "$($_.FullName)\PKA.dump") } | 
    select FullName
```

This will show the full path to all folders named *eV that don't contain a PKA.dump file. If that's not what you wanted, then at least it might give you some ideas.

(For future  reference, for these types of questions, you should show example inputs and expected outputs.)

Answer (score 0):

Add your path to the where your folder is and it should work.

```
$path = " "; # ADD YOUR PATH TO FOLDER HERE
$all_loc = Get-ChildItem -Recurse $path -Include "ev*" #Only looks where ev* exists

foreach ($x in $all_loc){ # look through all  "ev*" subsubfolders 
    $z = (Join-Path $x.FullName "PKA.dump") # variable to hold file name to search
    $test = Test-Path "$z" -PathType leaf;
    if ($test -eq 0){
        echo "$x does not contain PKA.dump";
        ## Uncomment below to create empty PKA.dump file
        #New-Item $z -type file
    }
}

## uncomment below to pause before closing
#$x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
```